# The php OR operand doesn't seem to work in a WordPress template file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is a weird one.  I'm working inside a PHP theme file in WordPress.

```
$a = false;
$b = true;

$c = $a OR $b;
```

$c is `false`

But

```
$c = $a || $b;
```

$c is, correctly, `true`.

I can create a function

```
function checkor($a, $b)
{
  return $a OR $b;
}
```

And this will correctly return `true` for the values above.

Any idea why the php `OR` operand doesn't appear to work in a WordPress theme template file?  (I'm running MAMP Pro on a Mac, PHP version 5.2.13.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Wordpress, and [is actually the way PHP works](http://viper-7.com/sVVL94).
It's called **Operator Precedence**.

To quote [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#example-122):

```
// "||" has a greater precedence than "or"

// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

Comment: So the equals assignment is getting precedence over the OR operator?  The reason that the function works is that it's returning the result? Your answer is obviously correct, but it's certainly a surprising result to me.

Comment: @ChristopherWerby - If you really want to use the literal `AND` & `OR` operators, just wrap 'em in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Check the PHP manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
// "||" has a greater precedence than "or"

// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I get it -- the equals assignment operator is evaluated first -- but that result certainly surprises me.  Seems like || and OR should be equivalent.  I also note that AND is similarly "flawed".  I prefer AND and OR for readability.  But I'll have to stop using them.